# enviar y recibir un parametro en ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Consulta. Tengo el siguiente codigo en un boton, dentro de una columna de una tabla

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnCobrar", function(){
    fila = $(this);           
    nro_socio = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()) ; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "acciones/cuotas_socios.js",
      //  datatype:"json",    
        data:  {nro_socio:nro_socio},    
        success: function() {
            alert(nro_socio);
             window.location.href = "cuotas_socio.php";
           }
        }); 
    });
```

y lo que necesito es que en el $(document).ready(function() { de otro js recibir el parametro ese, nro de socio, pero no se como se obtiene.

Comment: ¿Estas desarrollando en algun framework?

Comment: No, php,js,mysql